# Stats test to determine whether measurements within groups are constant

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anova, generalized-linear-model

I'm analysing a dataset with 50 polar bears, with three to seven home range size measurements (continuous variable) per bear taken in different years. I'm trying to test whether individual bears tend to keep the same home range size overtime.

I was originally thinking of doing an ANOVA, but I'm not sure that would work given the large number of groups and the fact that the measurements are not independent.

Would anyone have any suggestions regarding what stats test I could use instead? Maybe a GLM?

Comment: From your other question, you know about GLMMs (at least now you do).  Are you interested in *trends* in home range size, or do you just want to know whether there is year-to-year variability?